# explorer.exe only opens if I first terminate wsl

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an issue where if I enter `explorer.exe .` in wsl, nothing will happens and no explorer window is shown. However, if I first run `wsl -t Ubuntu-18.04` in powershell and rerun the command, explorer will open as expected. What caused this? I'm on Windows 10 1909.

EDIT:

However, if I run from powershell, the windows show, even though current Ubuntu-18.04 session didn't.

1. start powershell
2. `wsl`
3. `explorer.exe .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. This is because I run ssh daemon whenever the device boot up using task scheduler, and "Run whether user is logged on or not" is turned on (*this is important* because if it's off you won't have this issue). My `bat` script contains

```
%windir%\System32\bash.exe -c 'sudo /bin/mkdir -p /var/run/sshd'
%windir%\System32\bash.exe -c 'sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -D'
```

where `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -D` starts a "stuck" daemon, causing explorer.exe can't be opened in some way. This effectively causing any SSH into the system and running any .exe won't return any output too, for example `ssh user@thismachine "powershell.exe Get-Clipboard"`.

A perfect workaround for this issue would be:

https://gist.github.com/dentechy/de2be62b55cfd234681921d5a8b6be11#gistcomment-3036911

Quoting from the source, in case it got removed:

> ```
> Another way without Task Scheduler:
>
>     On the WSL put to the end of the /etc/sudoers file the following line:
>     %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/ssh start
>
>     Put to the shell:Startup folder bat file with the content:
>     powershell.exe "& 'C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe' -c 'sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start'"
>
> That's it!
>
> no sudo promt
> no Task Scheduler stuff
> no stucking daemon process like sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -D
> no WSL window open
> ```